# Detecting exact frequency of Bluetooth signal

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I was wondering if there was a way that I could detect the exact frequency of a BLE signal with an iphone.  I know it will be in the 2.4 GHz range but i would like to know the difference down to the 1 Hz range between the transmitted frequency and the received frequency.  The difference would be caused by the doppler effect meaning that the central or the peripheral would have to be moving.  Also is there an exact frequency that iphones transmit BLE at or does it depend on the iphone's antenna?

Comment: +1 for fancy question. I would be super surprised if such functionality was even exposed by the BT unit, let alone the OS but still, I like the question.

Answer (score 7):

Bluetooth doesn't have one particular frequency it operates on. Via [bluetooth.com](http://www.bluetooth.com/Pages/Basics.aspx):

> Bluetooth technology operates in the unlicensed industrial, scientific and medical (ISM) band at 2.4 to 2.485 GHz, using a spread spectrum, frequency hopping, full-duplex signal at a nominal rate of 1600 hops/sec.
>
> … adaptive hopping among 79 frequencies at 1 MHz intervals gives a high degree of interference immunity and also allows for more efficient transmission within the spectrum.

So there'll be a wide spread of frequencies in use for even a single connection to a single device. There's hardware on the market like the [Ubertooth](http://ubertooth.sourceforge.net) that can do packet captures and [spectrum analysis](http://ossmann.blogspot.com/2011/02/ubertooth-spectrum-analyzer.html).

To my knowledge, iOS doesn't offer API to find out this information. OS X does at some level, probably via SPI or an IOBluetooth API, because Apple's [Hardware Tools](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/) (search for "Bluetooth") offer a way to monitor spectrum usage of Bluetooth Classic devices on OS X.

As to your desire to detect movement via the Doppler effect on the radios, my instincts say that it's going to be very, very difficult to do. I'm not sure what the exact mathematics behind it would look like, but you'll want to examine what the Doppler effect on a transmission at 2.4 GHz would be as a result of low-to-moderate rates of motion. (A higher rate of motion or relative speed, say, over a few tens of miles an hour, will be quickly make Bluetooth the wrong radio technology to use because of its low transmit power.)

Comment: There is no frequency hopping during advertising which is primarily what my app will be working off of. The only time there is a frequency hop is after the connection.

Comment: There has to be a way to find the relative raw data for frequency. I just need to find somebody that can do it